# Python Pandas: How do I perform an operation on a shifted column within a group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have a dataframe in which I wish to perform a time difference operation on a shifted column within a group for work times. For example see data below:

```
 driver_id    veh                starttime                stoptime
0  kg123     10010      2018-12-21 15:17:29    2018-12-21 15:18:57
1  kg124     10012      2019-01-01 00:10:16    2019-01-01 00:16:32
2  kg124     10012      2019-01-01 00:27:11    2019-01-01 00:31:38
3  kg214     10012      2019-01-01 00:46:20    2019-01-01 01:04:54
4  kg125     10013      2019-01-01 00:19:06    2019-01-01 00:39:43
```

I wish to add a column that subtracts the next starttime for a driver in the same vehicle from the current stoptime so as to identify breaks between tasks. But I want to keep the operation within a group of my choosing, in this case driver_id and vehicle. output should look like this:

```
 driver-id  veh         starttime              stoptime      break_from_last
0  kg123   10010   2018-12-21 15:17:29 2018-12-21 15:18:57               NaT
1  kg124   10012   2019-01-01 00:10:16 2019-01-01 00:16:32               NaT
2  kg124   10012   2019-01-01 00:27:11 2019-01-01 00:31:38   0 days 00:21:22
3  kg124   10012   2019-01-01 00:46:20 2019-01-01 01:04:54   0 days 00:37:43
4  kg125   10013   2019-01-01 00:19:06 2019-01-01 00:39:43               NaT
```

In R this is simple as shown below using `data.table`:

```
 #starting shift

      j = c("driver_id","veh")
      df[,break_from_last:= round(
        as.numeric(difftime(starttime, shift(stoptime, 1L, type = "lag"),units ="hours"))
        ,2),by = j]
```

How do I accomplish this in python? I can produce a shifted difference, I just need the addition of the group. See below:

```
#produce a break
#BUT HOW DO I ADD A GROUP DESIGNATION?
df['break_from_last'] = df['stoptime'] - df['starttime'].shift(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, do a groupy and shift on starttime column the let pandas handle math operations using intrinsic data alignment on indexes:

```
df['break_from_last'] = df['stoptime'] - df.groupby('driver_id')['starttime'].shift()
df
```

Output:

```
  driver_id    veh           starttime            stoptime break_from_last
0     kg123  10010 2018-12-21 15:17:29 2018-12-21 15:18:57             NaT
1     kg124  10012 2019-01-01 00:10:16 2019-01-01 00:16:32             NaT
2     kg124  10012 2019-01-01 00:27:11 2019-01-01 00:31:38 0 days 00:21:22
3     kg124  10012 2019-01-01 00:46:20 2019-01-01 01:04:54 0 days 00:37:43
4     kg125  10013 2019-01-01 00:19:06 2019-01-01 00:39:43             NaT
```

Add `veh`,

```
df['break_from_last'] = df['stoptime'] - df.groupby(['driver_id', 'veh'])['starttime'].shift()
```

Output:

```
  driver_id    veh           starttime            stoptime break_from_last
0     kg123  10010 2018-12-21 15:17:29 2018-12-21 15:18:57             NaT
1     kg124  10012 2019-01-01 00:10:16 2019-01-01 00:16:32             NaT
2     kg124  10012 2019-01-01 00:27:11 2019-01-01 00:31:38 0 days 00:21:22
3     kg214  10012 2019-01-01 00:46:20 2019-01-01 01:04:54             NaT
4     kg125  10013 2019-01-01 00:19:06 2019-01-01 00:39:43             NaT
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work perfectly! I added the other column in as well: `df['break_from_last'] = df['stoptime'] - df.groupby(['driver_id', 'veh'])['starttime'].shift()`